# DragDrop event not raised

Tags: drag-and-drop, raiseevent

This is kind of a stupid question... I'm trying to drag and drop a picturebox onto a panel. I followed some exemples, but it doesn't work. The DragDrop event of the panel is never raised. I searched thi site for a solution andfound two topics over a year old, but their solutions did not work. I created a new project, with only this code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseDown);
            panel1.DragDrop +=new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);
            panel1.DragOver +=new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragOver);
        }

        private void panel1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DragOver");
        }

        private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DragDrop");
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse");
            pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Text, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
    }
```

I also set the AllowDrop of the panel and the form to true. DragOver and MouseDown are raised. Also, when I drag the picturebox, the cursor become a barred circled, like it was an operation that wasn't allowed. Is there a way that the cursor becomes the image in the picture box? I don't want the picturebox to move, only to add an item to the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard, the problem is that drag and drop is not as simple operation as you have coded here. Here you haven't started the drag movement which should start with code and you can read more about it here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=VS.90).aspx

If you just want to move the PictureBox... [dragging picturebox inside winform on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086989/dragging-picturebox-inside-winform-on-runtime)

And finally [Drag and Drop between Instances of the same Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201812/drag-and-drop-between-instances-of-the-same-windows-forms-application)

Hope this helps.

Comment: After a few trials, I fixed my problem about the dragdrop event not raising. The rest is working great. I only had to add this to for the dragdrop event to work.

private void canvasPanel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
             e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;;
        }

Comment: You are right! I just tried it and see what you mean. Nicely done :-)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is easy to solve.

You must just set in DragEnter appropriate Effect:

```
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}
```

After that DragDrop event is fired correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct solution. Like I mentioned in my comment three years ago, I used DragDropEffects.Move, instead of .All, which works too in my particular case.